# Animating crossover from object to object

Tags: animation, objects, boolean-modifier

I want to have different objects with different geometry nodes, shaders and modifiers to sort of cross over each other like in the example below. Here I have used boolean modifiers and some boxes to remove and reveal the desired object.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am afraid that this is a poor solution when the objects have more intricate details on them and the boolean will create artifacts. Is there a better way to achieve the same effect with other means?

[image]

Comment: you could try to do it with shader nodes like e.g. explained here: https://youtu.be/LbCKAlwxxmE